# Pandas function error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: pandas, series

I have a function to compared to date in a dataframe and return a value after a basic calculation:

```
def SDate(x,y):
    s=1
    a = min(x,y)
    b = max(x,y)
    if a !=x: s = -1
    r = b-a
    if b-a > 182:
        r = 365-b+a 
    return(r * s)
```

I have tried using the following but I have an error:

```
df['Result']= SDate(df['GL Date'].dt.dayofyear,df['Special Date'].dt.dayofyear )
```

but I have an

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Can you should your data frame? Also, are you trying to compare each corresponding value of GL date and Special date with min and max?

Comment: I have in each row of a dataframe two set of dates. I need to pass for each row the days from beginning of the year and apply the function which returns the shorter distance between these two date (considering that between Jan and Dec I need to have 1 and not 11 months).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but it looks like you are trying to set the inputs of a function to a series and get row wise outputs, which is unwise given that you want the output to be in the dataframe.

Its also good practice to include a sample of the data you are trying to use and what you want the output to look like, as well as a more detailed explanation of what you want to achieve.

That being said, from what you have described -you should use the apply method as a row wise operation to get your output.

So if you wish to apply this function:

```
def SDate(x,y):
    s=1
    a = min(x,y)
    b = max(x,y)
    if a !=x: s = -1
    r = b-a
    if b-a > 182:
        r = 365-b+a 
    return(r * s)
```

You should do this:

```
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda x: SDate(x['GL Date'].dt.dayofyear, x['Special Date'].dt.dayofyear), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving as `x` and as `y` a Pandas Series. Therefore, the function min cannot recieve such object. As I don't know what are you doing there I can't fix that on code.

Hope it works.

Comment: I need to pass the two date for each row of the dataframe to obtain a new column with the results of the function which is the distance between to date

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about `min/max` functions, they don't work with `Series` objects. Consider using this:

```
a = min(x.min(), y.min())
b = max(x.max(), y.max())
```

However, then you compare `Series` with a number: `if a != x:` – it will fail too. What's the purpose of your function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `axis` parameter of `df.apply`:

```
def SDate(row):
    s=1
    year1=row['GL Date'].year
    year2= row['Special Date'].year
    a = min(year1,year2)
    b = max(year1,year2)
    if a !=year1:
        s = -1
    r = b-a
    if b-a > 182:
        r = 365-b+a 
    return(r * s) 

df['Result']= df.apply(SDate, axis=1)
```

When you Pass the GL Date and Special Date years to the functions, you're actually passing in a `Series` The error is because you can't compare values of Series with `<` or `>` operators. So the results is ambiguous. Which is greater can't be determined. Hence the error that you got.

When you use apply functions `axis=1`, it applies the function row-wise.